# How to set different Binding to each Array element? C# UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, split, uwp

I managed to display my array in TextBlock - each [element] in separate row, but I would like to put each Array[index] element into separate TextBlock in the same Row, as long as it comes from same line, So:

1. A file is accessed
2. Lines are sorted
3. Lines are split into words
4. Each line is put on separate row

**5. Each word from line is put into separate TextBlock but within the same row.**

Here is my code:

```
public async void ReadFile()
    {
        var path = @"CPU.xls";
        var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

        var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
        var readFile = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
        foreach (string line in readFile.OrderBy(line =>
        {
            int lineNo;
            var success = int.TryParse(line.Split(';')[4], out lineNo);
            if (success) return lineNo;
            return int.MaxValue;
        }))
        {
            string[] splitLines = line.Split(';');

            for (int index = 0; index < splitLines.Length; index++)
            {
                itemsControl.Items.Add(splitLines[index]);
            }               
        }      
    }
```

As you can see above, I already did steps 1 - 4, unfortunately, at the moment each word goes into different row.

Here is bigger part of my xaml file:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl"
              ItemsSource="{Binding itemsControl}"
              FontSize="24">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="Auto"
                          Margin="0 12"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                                       
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                                        
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>                                    
                                 <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

I put two TextBlocks instead of 5 for now. How to make each of them getting different binding path to link with different array element?

----------UPDATE----------
I edited TextBlocks so each of them points to different array element like so:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=splitLines[0]}" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=splitLines[1]}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I don't get any errors at this point, but unfortunately no data is displayed at all. Why binding to array element is not working?

Comment: In this case, you'd be much better building this logic into your view model, and exposing a property of a `List<string[]>` (or `List<YourClass>`). You can then set that property to be your `ItemsSource` for the `ItemsControl`, and bind the columns to the fields as you like.

Comment: would you be so kind and provide some code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily setting `ItemsPanel` of `ItemsControl`

**EDIT**
Added `ItemTemplate` to `ItemsControl`

Say you had a `MainPage.xaml`

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="WordsList"
              ItemsSource="{Binding listOfWords}">
    <!-- Ensures each item is displayed horizontally -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <!--if you want each line in seperate TextBlock with more control-->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="22" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In code behind `MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    //Your intial string
    string words = "I am Line 1; I am Line 2; I am Line 3";

    //Using an ObservableCollection as works well with data binding
    public ObservableCollection<string> listOfWords { get; set; } = 
        new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //set the DataContext to this page
        this.DataContext = this;

        Loaded += (s, args) =>
        {
            var splitWords = words.Split(';');
            foreach(var word in splitWords)
            {
                //each line is added to listOfWords and can then be accessed by the ItemsControl as the ItemsSource
                //is set to listOfWords
                listOfWords.Add(word);
            }                
        };
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**
to bind to the array you will need a public property eg

```
public string[] splitLines { get; set; }
```

Comment: I got until this point, but the problem arises when I want to put each word from each line into separate column.

Comment: I dont understand if you want to Split by word then you would need to change your criteria to split on space space.

Comment: my C# code already gives me each word from each line, but I am unable to get binding to array[index]

Comment: I will try your solution today and will update what happens

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve it. I tried Your advice, but cannot think of way to implement it.